# Solr, Merge Facet from two taxonomy type fields

Tags: search

I am trying to create an advanced facet from a solr implementation.

A searchable content type (Book) has 2 fields (grade level min) and (grade level max) Grade level is a (Taxonomy Term) Pre-K - 12th.

I would like to create a facet called 'Grade' that when a user selects an option the search will use the grade min and max fields to filter this correctly. Example: (User clicks 6th Grade, the system will show all books whose min max values include 6th grade)

I am confident with providing the logic, I just don't know what hook, hooks, or UI options I can use to customize a facet to this degree. I am not new to Drupal but I am new to solr.

My initial thoughts are to either:

1. Add an aggregate field to store in the database
2. Create an advanced
   facet that can handle the min-max situation
3. Provide a hook before solr is accessed to modify my search
4. Provide a hook after solr returns results to modify my search.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by creating a new entity property in a custom module. This was kind of close to my 1st thought.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_property_info_alter().
 */
function advanced_search_entity_property_info_alter(&$info) {
    $info['node']['properties']['supported_grades'] = array(
        'type' => 'list<taxonomy_term>',
        'label' => t('Supported Grades'),
        'description' => t("Full Grade Level list that this resource has."),
        'sanitized' => TRUE,
        'getter callback' => 'advanced_search_get_supported_grades_callback',
    );
}

function advanced_search_get_supported_grades_callback($item) {
     // Logic that uses the $item values to return an array of tids.
}
```

Once I did this I was able to access the new field as usual when indexing and to create facets.

Hope this helps someone else out there.